# "If you don't think that X, which I personally do..." Does the speaker think X or not think X?

Tags: meaning-in-context, spoken-english, negation

I am puzzled with a meaning of a sentence with negation and referring to it.

When someone says:

> If you don't think that our case has been won, which I, personally do, then...

Is the person saying she/he agrees with the statement "our case has been won" or disagrees with it?

Comment: I think you should translate it into your native language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The speaker most likely thinks X** (in opposition to the listener).

Replace *think that our case has been won* with 'verb' *X*, expand the contraction and you have:

> If you **do not** X, which I personally **do**...

Does that make the contrast clearer?

Comment: @deff17 If this answered your question, please click the check mark next to my reply so others can see you no longer require assistance. Glad to help!

Answer (score 0):

I would say from my own understanding of the sentence, the  speaker does think X.

Comment: Welcome to English Language Learners! Please explain why your answer is correct; answers without explanation don't teach the patterns of English well and [may be deleted](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3294/18673).